# C# extend indexer?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, indexer

Is it possible to use extension methods to extend an indexer? I want to be able to get cell's value from `DataGridViewCell` of given `DataGridViewRow` using header text like this:

```
object o = row["HeaderText"];
```

I have this code

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static object Cells(this DataGridViewRow r, string header)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells)
        {
            if (c.OwningColumn.HeaderText == header)
            {
                return c.Value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and I want similar indexer. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Indexers are actually properties, and extension properties do not exist in C#. So this can't be done the way you want.

See [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-no-extension-properties) for some background on the subject, and an explanation as to why that feature was considered, but ultimately omitted from C# 3.0.

Answer (score 6):

No, it isn't. Extension methods are just syntactic sugar for static method call, an indexer is a property.

Doing

```
object o = new object();
o.ExtensionMethod();
```

is equivalent to

```
object o = new object();
Extensions.ExtensionMethod(o);
```

Extension methods don't change the class in any way, they just provide you with a simpler interface to call static methods.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.  This would effectively be an "extension property", which isn't supported.  You must have it as a method, like your current code.

Note that extension properties have been requested on Connect on [multiple](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/579470/extension-properties-in-vb-net-and-c) [occasions](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522888/extension-property), but have never been included in the language.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant extend operators, such as the indexer, with extension methods.

Comment: is indexer an operator in C#!

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible.  Extension methods are limited to methods only.  They can't provide properties, indexers or constructors

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for an extension property you can implement Getter and Setter Extension methods for object using reflection based object indexer code.