# c# extension for indexer

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to write an extension for DataRow indexer so I can do something like this:

```
MyCustomClass myClass;
DataRow[myClass] = 5;
```

I found this related question: [C# extend indexer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286181/c-sharp-extend-indexer)

However the question was asked 7 years ago and maybe we can extend indexers now?

Also in the [C# 8 sneak preview](https://blog.todotnet.com/2017/09/sneak-peek-at-c-8/) they mentioned "Extension Everything"

> For version 8 some features are in prototype status, some are just
>   concepts. The first four features that should make it to version 8 of
>   C# are:
>
> ```
> * Nullable Reference Types
> * Async Streams
> * Default Interface Methods
> * Extension Everything
> ```

Maybe I should wait for C# 8 to hit?

Comment: No, you can't write extension indexers yet. You *could* write an implicit conversion from `MyCustomClass` to `String` or `int` and use the existing indexers, but it's not really clear whether that's a good idea, based only on what you've shown.

Comment: Just write regular extension method, like `DataRow.Set(myClass, 5)`. Why it's so important for it to be indexer?

Comment: @Evk Why have operators at all? Why not use `1.Add(2.Multiply(3))` instead of `1+2*3`? Indexers (and other operators) convey implied meaning that must be learned (or validated) with named methods when used properly.